# New maui project on VS 2022 Preview 17.2 preview 3 doesn't correctly recognize the framerwork

Tags: visual-studio-2022, maui

Whenever I created a new project using the Maui RC Template,it shows the following error on  VS 2022 Preview 17.2

Error NETSDK1013 The TargetFramework value "6.0-android" was not recognized. It may be misspelled. If this is not the case, the TargetFrameworkIdentifier or TargetFrameworkVersion properties must be specified explicitly. MauiApp C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.300-preview.22204.3\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets 92

While using the template for non RC the preview 14 template in VS 2022 shows there isn't actually a problem but the debugging is broken... so I cant use breakpoints (It wont even start because it complains about the hot reload function which doesnt exist in VS 2022)

Comment: Valid tfms are documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#supported-target-frameworks).  So fix the typo to "net6.0-android".

Comment: @HansPassant if you see all these templates work with net6.0-android but for some reason when using RC Template is showing these errors and I believe it has to do with the target it is pointing to the 6.0.3 preview framework ...not sure if it would work the 6.0.2 version which was released yesterday or if one would be able to set it to use the non preview one